# Interpreting SHAP summary plots

Tags: classification, cart, lightgbm, shap, catboost

I am working on an attrition model. I have multiple categorical features with high cardinality. Hence I attempted Catboost and LightGBM for it.
I am also finding the SHAP plots for both. Following are my codes for it.

CatBoost:

```
import shap  # package used to calculate Shap values
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool
shap_values = clf.get_feature_importance(Pool(X_test, label=Y_test,cat_features=cat_features) ,
                                               type="ShapValues")
 
expected_value = shap_values[0,-1]
shap_values = shap_values[:,:-1]

shap.initjs()
```

lightGBM:

```
import shap 
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
base_value = explainer.expected_value[0]
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

My plots look as follows.

CatBoost

[image]

LightGBM

[image]

Why are my both plots looking different despite the fact that it is the same classification problem? I understand that both the codes used to find the SHAP Values are different and that might be the root cause. But I couldn't find anything relevant over the internet. How do I modify the lightGBM plot to make it look like the catboost plot?

Comment: Different models may have different opinions about what's important and what's not, and SHAP explains models.

Answer (score 0):

The plot of the CatBoost model is called [`beeswarm plot`](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/beeswarm.html?highlight=beeswarm). Adapting the example from the docs to your LightGBM code gives:

```py
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

# new
shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values)
```